# Connect to Mac Mini without sharing the screen

Tags: mac-mini, screen-sharing

When I connect to my mac mini (from my Mac Book Air) what happens is that the connection is made as a regular screen sharing. So if someone connects a screen to the mac mini then all the activity is seen.
But if there's already another user connected then I get a message saying that another user is already using the display, and then I can choose to share the screen or to "login as yourself", and that's great!

How can I always connect as login so each user get his privacy?

[image]
[image]

MacMini: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

MacBook AIr: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to do [file sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204445), but you're doing screen sharing for some reason...

Comment: Nope, just want to do what I just described

Comment: Are you sure? You didn't actually describe that we'll what you want to achieve with that. You described what you tried to do and it's not working. What you are trying to do is like connecting multiple mice to one computer and trying to let multiple people control it at the same time. That's why it's only letting one person do it at once. So my guess right now is that you want to allow multiple users to see the screen of that mac, but not interact with it in any way?

Comment: I'm trying to connect as a user, so multiple users can work at the same time

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean you just want to do file sharing? What's the value in having let's say 3 computers remote control one computer at the same time? A computer only has one mouse cursor. 3 people controlling the same cursor means nobody is going to be able to do anything, as they are all dragging the mouse cursor in different directions. I'm having super hard time understanding what you want to do.

Comment: But I do get to login with user A when user B is already logged in and using it. Each one connects from his own laptop

Answer (score 1):

Using other software, RealVNC, should fix your problem.

1. Download **[RealVNC](http://realvnc.com)**. You only need a personal license, which is free.
2. Enable **Remote Management**. Go into **System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Management**.
3. Configure RealVNC. It can be set up pretty much however you'd like.
4. Connect to your computer. This will land you on the login page for your mac, and will only share a screen with it if logged in as the current user.

Comment: I know about VNC but why can't I use it as a server? Isnt it a configuration issue that I can set? BTW the mac mini preferences are already set to File Sharing, Remote Login, and Remote Management

Answer (score 0):

I happened to find a solution for this involving the Guest User and automatic login…

https://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time/1469606#1469606